# Create a new column for Repeated elements in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

**I have a pandas data frame like**

```
DAYA TARIF SUBSIDI COUNT

450   B1    YES     8247


450   R1    YES     456

450   R1    NO     45

450   B1    NO     37
```

**CONVERT TO DATAFRAME**

```
DAYA TARIF YES NO 

450 B1  8247 37

450 R1  456  45
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: Use: `df.pivot(index=['DAYA', 'TARIF'], columns='SUBSIDI', values='COUNT')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using `pivot_table`:

```
import pandas as pd
new = (pd.pivot_table(df,index=['DAYA','TARIF'],columns = 'SUBSIDI',values='COUNT')).reset_index()
```

will get you:

```
SUBSIDI  DAYA TARIF  NO   YES
0         450    B1  37  8247
1         450    R1  45   456
```